# Change or transform metric name globally in grafana charts or queries

Tags: prometheus, grafana, thanos

I'm currently in the process of upgrading our monitoring services (Prometheus/Grafana/Thanos), and noticed that some of the metrics names in kube-state-metrics v2.0.0 will change: `kube_hpa_*` will be renamed to `kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_*`upon upgrade.

I'm wondering if there is any way to avoid updating this metrics defined in every Grafana chart. For example, a global way of configuring Grafana so that kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_* replaces kube_hpa_* in any chart already configured. Or even better, making one the alias of another.

I've looked into using `relabel_config` in prometheus, but as the name suggests this is to rename labels, not metrics.